# Use CSS to make an arrow instead of rounding corners

Tags: html, css

I have a link which is a box like the SO 'Ask Question' button but I want the right of it to point like an arrow.

This http://jsfiddle.net/U4zXS/1/ is what I have so far. I have the right side rounded but I need it to be in a point like an arrow.

```
<a class="arrow_link" href="{$base_url}signup">GET STARTED WITH OUR <span class="purple">FREE TRIAL</span></a>


.arrow_link{
    float: left;
    background-color: $color-orange;
    border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
    padding: 4px 15px 6px 8px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $color-white;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Checkout the triangle generator: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: or this http://cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with the borders triangle method:

```css
.arrow_link::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #F78E1E;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Notice that you'll also have to add `position: relative` to the `.arrow_link` itself.

Here's the updated fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U4zXS/5/)

Comment: Thanks this works grand on the links but will it not work on a submit button? Doesn't seem to hav an affect

Comment: @PierceMcGeough you mean `<input type="submit">`? If so, it won't work because `<input>` tag can't have children elements. `::after` pseudo element is rendered as the child of an element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS `:after` psuedo-element as followed:

```
.arrow_link { position: relative; }
.arrow_link:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   border: 10px solid transparent;
   border-left-color: red;
   top: 0;
   right: -20px;
}
```

This will append a psuedo-element to your `a`, which will show the arrow using the border trick as explained very well on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo element to make the triangle at the end of the element. Here is some more [info about pseudo elements](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/) that should help you get started with them.

Here is the changed css:

```
.arrow_link{
    float: left;
    background-color: $color-orange;
    padding: 4px 15px 6px 8px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $color-white;
    position: relative;
}
.arrow_link:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 15px solid #f78e1e;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U4zXS/7/)

The only problem you will have is due to your element not having a fixed height, won't be a problem if your element doesn't change. CSS triangles are not the most flexible thing to use but they do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/WW32n/1/ and some references here http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

```
<p class="triangle-isosceles right">The entire appearance is created only with CSS.</p>
```

and the css

```
.triangle-isosceles {
  position:relative;
  padding:15px;
  margin:1em 0 3em;
  color:#000;
  background:#f3961c; /* default background for browsers without gradient support */
  /* css3 */
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f9d835), to(#f3961c));
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(#f9d835, #f3961c);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(#f9d835, #f3961c);
  background:linear-gradient(#f9d835, #f3961c);
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}

/* creates triangle */
.triangle-isosceles:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-15px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:50px; /* controls horizontal position */
  border-width:15px 15px 0; /* vary these values to change the angle of the vertex */
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#f3961c transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}
```